Im trying to run this deep learning algorithm for FER but i keep getting this same in_channels argument error no matter what fix I try
i keep receiving this specific error for my deep learning algorithm using resnet50 model, where it states that TypeError: ResMasking.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'in_channels'.
I tried multiple fixes and tried implementing code from GPT-4 but i keep coming back to the same error no matter the fix.
text
Need some assistance to overcome this error
